# Joining 3 tables in PHP query

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

Alright so for some reason I cant join 3 tables properly in with PHP and MySQL. My query worked with 2 but with 3 it wont.

```
select users.username,
    users.ID,
    users.currentTime,
    users.gender,
    user_ranks.likes as likes,
    user_ranks.disslikes as diss,
    profiles.img_url as URL
from users
inner join profiles,
    user_ranks on users.ID = profiles.userID LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You only have one `on`. How does the third table join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join both tables with an `ON` clause:

```
select users.username,
    users.ID,
    users.currentTime,
    users.gender,
    user_ranks.likes as likes,
    user_ranks.disslikes as diss,
    profiles.img_url as URL
from users
inner join profiles on users.ID = profiles.userID
inner join user_ranks on user_ranks.ID = profiles.userID 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hmmm yep that makes sense, I didnt know I had to join 2 times, went full retard haha. Thanks mate, highly appreciated. Ill mark it as correct answer as soon as stackoverflow allows me to!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.username,
    users.ID,
    users.currentTime,
    users.gender,
    user_ranks.likes as likes,
    user_ranks.disslikes as diss,
    profiles.img_url as URL
FROM users 
INNER JOIN profiles
    on users.ID = profiles.userID
INNER JOIN user_ranks
    on user_ranks.ID = profiles.userID
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    users.username,
    users.ID,
    users.currentTime,
    users.gender,
    user_ranks.likes as likes,
    user_ranks.disslikes as diss,
    profiles.img_url as URL
FROM users
INNER JOIN profiles ON users.ID = profiles.userID 
INNER JOIN tbl_3 ON users.col = tbl_3.fk
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a join for each of the tables. for Example:

```
select users.username,
users.ID,
users.currentTime,
users.gender,
user_ranks.likes as likes,
user_ranks.disslikes as diss,
profiles.img_url as URL from users 
inner join profiles on users.ID = profiles.userID 
inner join user_ranks on users.ID= user_ranks.ID LIMIT 1
```